# LZ77 algorithm - the next char in the tuple

Tags: algorithm, compression

To describe my questions, let's take a look the example on Wiki:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LZ77_and_LZ78#Example

I have 2 questions:
1) why always keep the next character? In some sense the next char is not compressed because it is stored into the tuple directly.

2) what if the reserved termination symbol ("$" in the example) actually appears in the input data? There is a chance to be stored as the next char which really means the next char is "$", right? If we have every char appearing as the next char, what is the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Once you've found the longest match, the next character, by definition, cannot be represented as part of a match, so it must be sent literally to the decompressor.

2) "$" is used figuratively in the example to represent the end of the input. It is normally represented by its own code that is independent of the 256 literal bytes.

Comment: 1) so in the next iteration, why not just search the matched pattern starting with the nex chararcter?

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking.

Comment: I mean, why not return a pair fo values: one is the distance, and the second one is either length or next character, depending on whether distance is zero or not(when the distance is zero, the second value is the next character). 
By doing this, 'next character' doesn't need to be always sent literally to the decompressor, but only when the character cannot be found in the search buffer.

Comment: There are many representations of the same data. In deflate there is a singe literal/length code, where a distance follows only if the code is a length. (And by the way, the literals are compressed.) In brotli a single code represents a length and the number of literals, followed by literal codes, followed by a distance for the copy. The "tuples" are not necessarily how they are coded, just the information that need to be conveyed.